# Find words in a column per row after list of specific words in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column named "warranty" that contains records of various ways to fix different issues, as shown below:

|  | wnum | warranty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | replace battery wire from car |
| 1 | 101 | clean fuel tank |
| 2 | 102 | remove nail from tire |

Code for initialize:

```py
df.pdDataFrame({
  'wnum'    : [100, 101, 102],
  'warranty': ['replace battery wire from car', 'clean fuel tank', 'remove nail from tire']
})
```

My goal is to extract the words following the specific words listed below:

```
word_list=['replace', 'clean', 'remove']
```

How can I achieve this, and get the expected output of a new column added to the above DataFrame with the values "replace battery," "wire clean," "fuel tank," and "remove nail"?

Comment: Welcome to SO :)
Please add a toy example of data and expected output based on it. It should be in the form of a codesnippet.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: it may need to use `.apply()` with function which run loop `for word in word_list` and check if this word is in string in text. OR you may try to use `regex` like `"replace|clean|remove"` to search in text. (`"|".join(word_list)`)

Comment: it would much simpler if you would put example data as text - `pd.DataFrame(..)` - because we could simply copy it and use for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` can use `regex` to search string and you could use pattern to

```
(?:replace|clean|remove) (\w+)
```

You can use python to generate this pattern

```
words = "|".join(word_list)
pattern = f'(?:{words}) (\w+)'

print('pattern:', pattern)
```

And later

```
df['word'] = df['warranty'].str.lower().str.findall(pattern).str[0]
```

To make sure I convert text to `lower()` because pattern uses lower case words.

---

If `replace,clean,remove` is always as first word then you could simply `split(" ")` text and get second element:

```
df['word'] = df['warranty'].str.split(' ').str[1]
```

---

If you need more complex code then you could use `.apply()`

```
def function(text):
    # ... complex code ...
    return text.split(' ')[1]

df['word'] = df['warranty'].apply(function)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'warranty': [
        'replace battery wire from car',
        'clean fuel tank',
        'remove nail from tire',
    ], 
}

word_list=['replace', 'clean', 'remove']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

words = "|".join(word_list)
pattern = f'(?:{words}) (\w+)'
print('pattern:', pattern)

def function(text):
    # ... complex code ...
    return text.split(' ')[1]

df['method1'] = df['warranty'].str.lower().str.findall(pattern).str[0]
df['method2'] = df['warranty'].str.split(' ').str[1]
df['method3'] = df['warranty'].apply(function)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
pattern: (?:replace|clean|remove) (\w+)

                        warranty  method1  method2  method3
0  replace battery wire from car  battery  battery  battery
1                clean fuel tank     fuel     fuel     fuel
2          remove nail from tire     nail     nail     nail
```